# Making div width equal to the longest word/sentence length inside it

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I want to make **div width equal to content longest word/sentence** length. Here is sample:

```
<div id="1">I_want_to_make_div_width_equal_to_this_word</div>
```

It works fine with this css code:

```
div {display: inline-block;}
```

It also works in this example:

```
<div id="2"> I_want_to_make_div_width_equal_to_this_word <br/> 
             and_anther_word_in_next_line </div>
```

Div with id="2" has a width of the longest word.

**But my problem is with this example.** When content window is too small to contain both words in one line, div have width of 100% window size:

```
<div id="3"> I_want_to_make_div_width_equal_to_this_word
             and_anther_word_in_next_line </div>
```

**Is it possible for the div with id=3 to behave like id=2 but without `<br />` sign?**

Examples I just described: http://jsfiddle.net/2vffqrwy/ (make width of window that break words in third div into two separate lines).

*Edit:*
The perfect solution is when div id=3 display both words in one line when window is big enough and behaves like div id=2 when window is to small to contain both words in one line.

Comment: how does typography affect this? How are you taking into account differing character widths between styles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New Edit from OP's comments :

The only way I can see to resolve this is using javascript,
I made a uggly and probably overkilling snippet which does the work :
It creates a clone of the node, set it as `inline` with `white-space: nowrap` and then add each word one at a time, compare the clone width with parent's width. If it's larger, then it assigns `display: table-caption` to the orginal div, else it adds the next word.

**CSS**

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:pink;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
.caption {
    display : table-caption;
}
.cloned {
    visibility : hidden;
    white-space : nowrap;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
 var clone, el,w;

(cloneIt)();
function cloneIt(){
    el = document.getElementById('3');
    clone = el.cloneNode(true);
    clone.className = "cloned";
    el.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    w = clone.innerHTML.split(' ');
    wrapIt();
}
window.onresize = wrapIt;

function wrapIt(){
    clone.innerHTML = w[0]; //minimum content is first word
    for(i=1; i<w.length; i++){
        clone.innerHTML += w[i]+' ';//add next word
        if(i==w.length-1 && clone.offsetWidth <= el.parentNode.offsetWidth){
            //we're at the end and it's still smaller than parent width?
            el.style.width = clone.offsetWidth+ 1 + 'px';
            return;
            }
        if(clone.offsetWidth <= el.parentNode.offsetWidth){ 
            //add a new word
            continue;
        }
        //Gone too far? remove last word
        clone.innerHTML = clone.innerHTML.replace(w[i], '');
        el.style.width = clone.offsetWidth+ 1 + 'px';
        return;
     }
}
```

[**Here is Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/tqyu7fg7/3/)

Comment: You gave the same result as @Eiiki with the same problem: **You can't with this solution show both words in one line when window is big enough**.

Comment: @Everettss Updated answer, using javascript sorry…

Comment: I'm not close-minded for any ideas! It's nice what You did. Mayby because of lack of precision in my question i see one more litle problem in Your answer: **what happen when there will by more than 2 words?** It's imposible with your answer to have div width equal to first two words and third in another line. Here's example: http://jsfiddle.net/tqyu7fg7/

Comment: @Everettss Ok, wasn't simple but I think the new edit does what you want, in a hacky and uggly way (lot of calculations each time you resize the window). I don't think you can use it on every div you'll have in your page but it does the work and can provide some clue to do it better

Answer (score 0):

You must set a width for your div, or you can put your text inside a `<p></p>`  tag and set the width for your paragraph on CSS.

Example:

```
#3 {
 width: 300px;
}
```

or, if you want something more semantic:

```
#3 p {
  width: 300px;

}
```

Comment: It's not elegant solution. Look on the @Arthur answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually impossible to create linebreak without wraping the elements around something like a span or a div for example. 
So make the html like this:

```
<div id="1">I_want_to_make_div_width_equal_to_this_word</div>
<div id="2">I_want_to_make_div_width_equal_to_this_word
   <br/>and_anther_word_in_next_line
</div>
<div id="3">
   <span>I_want_to_make_div_width_equal_to_this_word</span>
   <span>and_anther_word_in_next_line</span>
</div>
```

And the CSS like this:

```
div span{
   display:block;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vffqrwy/4/)

Comment: Your answer is great until I dont make window size big enough to contain two words in one line. But I like your point - it's getting us closer!