# Button with Icon and text using minimal width

Tags: html, css

I have a simple Html button with an icon on top, and a description below.

```
<div class="mybtn">
    <div><img src="someimage.png"></div>
    <div>Button description</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible using css, to minimize the width of this button, so the description wraps if it is wider than the image? The description should also be horizontally centered below the image.

The result should be like this: https://jsfiddle.net/c3trL3ha/ but where the width of "mybtn" is not defined. As you can see, "mybtn" is as narrow as possible.

Comment: Try using `max-width` on your `mybtn`.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `width` and `word-wrap: break-word` on `.mybtn > div`, like this:

```
.mybtn > div {
  width: 32px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.mybtn img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6shgm6jb/1/)

Note: As said in comment, it is not suggested in User Experience (UX) aspect, as a word will be separated into multiple lines.

Comment: The image is 32x32 pixels. I don't see what defining the width of the image solves. The button should be as narrow as possible.

Comment: Check my updated answer. You should consider using `word-wrap: break-word`. However, it is not suggested in User Experience (UX) aspect, as a word will be separated into multiple lines.

Comment: I do not want to break up words. The width of the button should be: Max(image-width, longest-word-length). You can see in my updated answer how it should look. The text will of course be different for each button.

Comment: I tried your JSFiddle, but it is contradicting the behavior of CSS, where the text will not wrap if the width is not defined. I believe this scenario is not your final one, as this may yield unpredictable layout in your site. The best bet for you is to replace the space with line breaks `<br />` with JS dynamically, after calculating the right space required, as longest word length cannot be obtained via CSS. Please see [this similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273519/making-div-width-equal-to-the-longest-word-sentence-length-inside-it)

Comment: Okay, thanks for  your answer. Should I mark your answer as solution, even though it did not fix my initial question?

Comment: As you like @stefan. If you have any further question, you can create a new question, I would be happy to help you again.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9p1g7pqx/) fiddle

**CSS**

```
.mybtn{
  width: 200px;
}
.mybtn div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
```